# Association table as @Entity versus @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

On an existant code base, when I looked to perform a join for a `@ManyToMany` relationship, I saw no `@ManyToMany` fields on business tables `@Entity` but only in the join table defined as `@Entity`. In other words I was expecting:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee { 
    // ...
  
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Employee_Project", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }
    )
    Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
    
    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {    
    // ...  
  
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
     
    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
}
```

But I saw:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee { 
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {    
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee_Project")
public class EmployeeProject { 
    // ...
  
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "Employee_FK_ID", nullable = false)
    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
  
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "Project_FK_ID", nullable = false)
    Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
    
    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}
```

After a short discussion with a senior developer, he told me the latter is better because there is no bi-directional relationship.

I don't understand why is it a problem? It seems to me that:

1. The bi-directional relationship still exists in the physical data model
2. In the former, there is one owner of the relationship
3. It overcomplicates things when performing joins (the joins order become important)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We are using the second approach sometimes, for only one reason - not to load too much data. You can use Employee and only when you need the data for the projects get it from EmployeeProject.